# Can the server be nio and clients blocking

Tags: java, netty, nio

I am using netty to change our servers to support nio. Do i also need to change the clients to support nio or they can work as they are.

EDIT:
I wrote a small test, i am able to send data to the Server but Data Sent by server to client is not received.

Please see the code sample below:
SERVER:

```
public class NettyNioServer {
    private static final int BACKLOG = 1000;
    private final int port;

    public NettyNioServer(int port){
        this.port = port;
    }

    public void start() throws Exception{
        EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        try{
            final ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel> channelInitializer = new BasicSocketChannelInitializer();
            ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
            b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
             .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
             .childHandler(channelInitializer)
             .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, BACKLOG)
             .option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true);
            ChannelFuture f = b.bind(port).sync();
            System.out.println("* * * Mediation Server Started on Port: "+port+" * * *");
            Main.getLogWrapper1().log(Level.INFO, "* * * Mediation Server Started on Port: "+port+" * * *");
            f.channel().closeFuture().sync();
        }catch(Exception e){
            Main.getLogWrapper1().log(Level.FATAL, "***** Could not listen on Port ****");
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
            Main.getLogWrapper1().log(Level.FATAL, sw.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
            bossGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        }
    }
}

public class BasicNioServerHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter{

    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
        String message = (String) msg;
        try{
            System.out.println(message);
            if (message != null && message.length()>0) {
                //New Code Start Here
                FrameProcessor frameProcessor = new FrameProcessor(null,Main.getLogWrapper1(),new Util());
                final String msgResponse = frameProcessor.frameDataProcess(message,"");              
                final ChannelFuture f = ctx.writeAndFlush(msgResponse+"\r\n");
                f.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) throws Exception {
                        System.out.println("Message Sent to COMM: ACK="+msgResponse);
                    }
                });

            }
        }finally{
            ReferenceCountUtil.release(msg);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) throws Exception {
        cause.printStackTrace();
        Main.getLogWrapper1().log(Level.ERROR, cause.getMessage());
        //ctx.close();
    }  
}

public class BasicSocketChannelInitializer extends ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>{

    private static final StringDecoder STRING_DECODER = new StringDecoder(CharsetUtil.UTF_8);
    private static final StringEncoder STRING_ENCODER = new StringEncoder(CharsetUtil.UTF_8);

    @Override
    protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
        ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();
        //Decoders
        pipeline.addLast("frameDecoder", new DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(8192, Delimiters.lineDelimiter()));
        pipeline.addLast("stringDecoder", STRING_DECODER);
        pipeline.addLast(new BasicNioServerHandler());
        //Encoders
        pipeline.addLast("stringEncoder", STRING_ENCODER);
    }

}
```

Blocking Client:

```
try{
       socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 5552);
       out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
       in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
       input = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
     } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
       System.out.println("Unknown host");
       System.exit(1);
     } catch  (IOException e) {
       System.out.println("No I/O");
       System.exit(1);
     }
out.println(text);
         System.out.println("Data Sent :" + text);


//Receive text from server
       try{
      //String line = in.readLine();
           byte[] buffer =new byte[100]; 
           int bytes = input.read(buffer);
          System.out.println("Data Received From Server :" + new String(buffer));
       } catch (IOException e){
     System.out.println("Read failed");
         System.exit(1);
       }
```

Note both readLine and read(byte[]) does not receive the message. Whereas the ChannelFuture prints the message as successfully sent.
Also i have sent simple string, string+"\r\n",string+"\n", but i do not receive message at the client.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's all TCP. Blocking/non-blocking/asynchronous are properties of the API, not of the protocol.

Comment: Please see the edited question and let me know why i am unable to get the response as client

Comment: You are now asking a completely different question. You've provided no evidence that anything is ever being sent. You have double backslashes where you should have single.